# SAP UI5 XML View Data Binding syntax

Tags: sapui5

I try to figure out how I can bind data to `sap.m.CustomListItem` during `onInit` of my controller. I tried a lot but nothing seems to fit. It looks so easy on the examples from the UI5 Demo Kit.

```xml
<mvc:View
  height="100%"
  controllerName="sap.ui.demo.toolpageapp.controller.settings.MasterSettings"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <List>
    <items items="{folder>objects}">
      <CustomListItem items="{folder>/object/properties/cmis:name/value}">
        <Link id="text6"
          maxLines="0"
          text="{folder>/object/properties/['cmis:objectId']/displayName}" />
        <OverflowToolbar id="otbFooter">
          <Button type="Accept" text="Accept">
            <layoutData>
              <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
            </layoutData>
          </Button>
          <Button type="Reject" text="Reject">
            <layoutData>
              <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
            </layoutData>
          </Button>
        </OverflowToolbar>
        <SearchField/>
      </CustomListItem>
    </items>
  </List>
</mvc:View>
```

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/demo/toolpageapp/controller/BaseController",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/demo/toolpageapp/model/formatter"
], function(BaseController, MessageToast, JSONModel, formatter) {
  "use strict";
  var cmisRootFolder;
  var children;

  return BaseController.extend("sap.ui.demo.toolpageapp.controller.settings.MasterSettings", {
    formatter: formatter,
    onInit: function() {
      getCMISFolderStructure();
      var oModel = new JSONModel(cmisRootFolder);
      this.setModel(oModel, "folder");
      console.log(oModel);

      function processRootFolder(data) {
        cmisRootFolder = data;
      }

      function getCMISFolderStructure() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          }
        });
        const session = new cmis.createSession("http://localhost:8080/myTest/browser");
        session.setCredentials('test', 'test').getFolderTree("rfHN5c3RlbXwxfHJlcG8xfC8=", 2, {
          request: {
            async: false,
            success: processRootFolder,
            error: function(e) {
              if (e)
                console.log(false, "Error during the request: " + e);
              else
                console.log(false, "Error during the request: " + e);
            }
          }
        })
      }
    },

    onMasterPressed: function(oEvent) {
      var oContext = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext("side");
      var sPath = oContext.getPath() + "/selected";
      oContext.getModel().setProperty(sPath, true);
      var sSelectedMasterElement = oContext.getProperty("title");
      var sKey = oContext.getProperty("key");
      switch (sSelectedMasterElement) {
        case "System Settings": {
          this.getRouter().navTo(sKey);
          break;
        }
        default: {
          MessageToast.show(sSelectedMasterElement + " was pressed");
          break;
        }
      }
    },

    onToggleOpenState: function(oEvent) {
      var iItemIndex = oEvent.getParameter("itemIndex");
      var oItemContext = oEvent.getParameter("itemContext");
      var bExpanded = oEvent.getParameter("expanded");
      MessageToast.show("Item index: " + iItemIndex +
        "\nItem context (path): " + oItemContext +
        "\nExpanded: " + bExpanded, {
          duration: 5000,
          width: "auto"
        });
      var oTree = this.byId("Tree");
      var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
      var sPath = oItemContext.getPath();
      var bChildIsDummyNode = oModel.getProperty(sPath + "/nodes/0").dummy === true;
      if (bExpanded && bChildIsDummyNode) {
        this.loadData(oModel, sPath, oTree.getItems()[iItemIndex].getLevel());
      }
    },

    loadData: function(oModel, sPath, iLevel) {
      var oTree = this.byId("Tree");

      function processRootFolder(data) {
        cmisRootFolder = data;
      }
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
      });
      const session = new cmis.createSession("http://localhost:8080/myTest/browser");
      session.setCredentials('test', 'test').getFolderTree("rfHN5c3RlbXwxfHJlcG8xfC8=", 2, {
          request: {
            async: false,
            success: processRootFolder,
            error: function(e) {
              if (e)
                console.log(false, "Error during the request: " + e);
              else
                console.log(false, "Error during the request: " + e);
            }
          }
        }),
        // In this example we are just pretending to load data from the backend.
        //oTree.setBusy(true);
        setTimeout(function() {
          var aNewNodes = [cmisRootFolder];
          oModel.setProperty(sPath ? sPath + "/nodes" : "/", aNewNodes);
          //oTree.setBusy(false);
          console.log(oModel);
        }, 2000);
    },

    onSavePressed: function() {
      MessageToast.show("Save was pressed");
    },

    onCancelPressed: function() {
      MessageToast.show("Cancel was pressed");
    },

    onNavButtonPress: function() {
      this.getOwnerComponent().myNavBack();
    }
  });
});
```

I found an example in the internet and it looked like it's exactly that what I need. And that is what you see in the code example above. But it does not work.

Comment: Off-topic but `async: false` (in controller) really needs to be avoided. Especially if you already have a dedicated success handler. Sending synchronous XHR freezes the UI (main) thread of the browser which results in a bad UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find the code snippets? There are too many errors.

> ```
> items="{folder>objects}"
> ```

The binding paths in the view need to be corrected. According to your data, it should be `items="{folder>/objects}"` i.e. *absolute* binding path (Slash after `>` is missing).

[Documentation: Binding Path](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9)

---

> ```
> <items items="{folder>objects}">
> ```

Named aggregation nodes cannot have aggregation binding. Only ManagedObjects (Controls) support binding properties, aggregations, and contexts.
Move the aggregation binding to the `<List>`.

---

> ```
> <CustomListItem items="{...}">
> ```

[`sap.m.CustomListItem`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.CustomListItem#aggregations) doesn't have `items`-aggregation at all.

---

> ```
> text="{folder>/object/properties/['cmis:objectId']/displayName}"
> ```

According to your data, `properties` is not an array but an object, so you cannot apply xpath-like syntax such as `/['cmis:objectId']/`. Also, you can make use of the context that was passed to the children (resulted from aggregation binding). No need to assign an *absolute* binding path.
Remove the first slash after `>` to make it *relative*.

---

## TL;DR

Try with:

```xml
<List items="{folder>/objects}">
  <CustomListItem>
    <Link text="{folder>properties/cmis:objectId/displayName}" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

- [Topic: Data Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247)
- [Tutorial: Data Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c)